# VBA type 13 error (type mismatch) occuring when attempting to use cell value for a case statement

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code I am trying to run:

```
    Sub SystemSelection()
    ' This function checks what the selected wire run type is.
    
    Dim SystemSelection As Variant
    
    SystemSelection = Sheets(Sheet1).Range(M4).Value
    MsgBox (SystemSelection)
    
    Select Case SystemSelection
    
    Case Is = "case1"
    Test
    
    
    Case Is = "case2"
    Test
    
    
    Case Else
    MsgBox ("Error encountered - unknown system type selected")
    
    End Select
    
    End Sub

Sub Test()
MsgBox (Testing)
End Sub
```

However, it fails on runtime with a code 13 type mismatch error when selecting the value of the excel cell at m4. As basic as this error is I cannot figure out why this is happening, i've formated the cell as a string.

Comment: `Sheets(Sheet1).Range(M4).Value` ----> `Sheet1.Range("M4").Value`

Comment: Side note, you should not be using `()` with `MsgBox` here.

Comment: `Case Is = "case1"` ----> `Case "case1"`

Comment: `MsgBox (Testing)` ----> `MsgBox "Testing"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing inverted commas in:

```
SystemSelection = Sheets(Sheet1).Range(M4).Value
```

Change this to

```
SystemSelection = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M4").Value
```